# find the textfield which has got maximum value-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 input text fields  on 5 rows . where all 5 textfields are optional .i want to get the id of the  text field which has got maximum value

```
<div class="dt_distance_slab">
     <g:textField class ="number distanceSlab1" name="distanceSlabCost1" id = "distanceSlabCost1"  value=""/> 
  </div>
<div class="dt_distance_slab">
     <g:textField class ="number distanceSlab2" name="distanceSlabCost2" id = "distanceSlabCost2"  value=""/> 
  </div>
  <div class="dt_distance_slab">
     <g:textField class ="number distanceSlab3" name="distanceSlabCost3" id = "distanceSlabCost3"  value=""/> 
  </div>
   <div class="dt_distance_slab">
     <g:textField class ="number distanceSlab4" name="distanceSlabCost4" id = "distanceSlabCost4"  value=""/> 
  </div>
    <div class="dt_distance_slab">
     <g:textField class ="number distanceSlab5" name="distanceSlabCost5" id = "distanceSlabCost5"  value=""/> 
  </div>
```

i have done a validation that  input fields will aceept only numbers and values should be in ascending order.

Comment: Make your question clearer, the title of your question and the description don't really make sense with one another.

Comment: i want to get the id of the textfield which has got maximum value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit complicated but it works good:

```
var id = $(".number").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).last().attr("id");
```

It gets all the inputs, filters those that have value and returns an id of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInput() {
    var lastInputId = null;

    $('g:textField').each(function(i, item) {
        item.value && (lastInputId = item.id);
    });
    return lastInputId;
}
```

Comment: i dint get the answer... what it will return?

Answer (score 0):

```
function determineLastWithValue = function() {
    var lastWithValue, iset = $('.dt_distance_slab > input'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < iset.length; i++) {
        if (iset[i].value == '') {
            break;
        }
        lastWithValue = iset[i];
    }
    return lastWithValue;
}
```