# Loop through input fields with jQuery to find the highest value?

Tags: jquery

I have a number of `input[type=text]` fields on my page and I want to loop through all of them in order to find and return the highest value.

Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the textfield which has got maximum value-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282179/find-the-textfield-which-has-got-maximum-value-jquery)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
var highest = -Infinity;
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    highest = Math.max(highest, parseFloat(this.value));
});
console.log(highest);
```

Here is another solution:

```
var highest = $("input[type='text']").map(function() {
    return parseFloat(this.value);
}).get().sort().pop();

console.log(highest);
```

Comment: No reason for a duplicate answer... +1

Comment: And how about this? 
highest = Math.max(highest, this.value*1);
for avoid non-numeric values and NaN

Comment: $(...).map(...).sort(...).pop is not a function

Comment: @vee Back to 2012 `map()` was returning array-like jQuery collection object with array prototype methods. Now we have to be strict and use `get()` to receive pure JavaScript array from jQuery collection. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Math.max](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp) function:

```
var nums = [];
$("input[type=text]").each( function() { nums.push( $(this).val() ); });
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, nums);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will try this one as well.